# Update position of libgdx box2dlights ConeLight

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

As the title says, I'm trying to update the position of a conelight in the box2dlight library.

Currently, I define the ConeLight as c1 in the create method.

```
ConeLight c1 = new ConeLight(handler,5000,Color.BLUE,400,(width/2f)+50,(height/2f)+15,-90,40);
```

I tried changing the position of c1 in the update method but I can't get the variable from inside that method and have no idea how to as I'm new to Java as a whole.

How can I constantly update c1's position (eg: move it from left to right, follow player etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a method that fixes my problem called "attachToBody" which does as the name suggests; attaches it to a body so it constantly follows it

I use it like this:

```
ConeLight c1 = new ConeLight(handler,5000,Color.BLUE,400,(width/2f)+50,(height/2f)+15,-90,40);
c1.attachToBody(circleBody);
```